# How to mock methods which has parameters with @Value annotated class/member variables?

Tags: spring-boot, junit5, spring-boot-test

I have 3 classes involved in my problem: `MyService`, `MyServiceTest`, `MyConfig` and a yaml file `application.yml`. `MyRequest` and `MyResponse` are my custom classes which denotes the incoming request to service class from controller and outgoing response from service class to controller respectively.

***I am getting below error:***

> SAAJ007: Bad Endpoint type

**application.yml**

```yaml
    backside:
      url: https://mybackend.com/my/operation
    ssl:
      store: D:\\mydata\\myconfiguration\\mykey.jks
      token: password
```

**MyService.java**

```java
    @Service
    public class MyService{
        @Value("${backside.url}")
        private String backsideUrl;    
        
        private MyFormatter formatter; // has methods which formats request and response
        private SOAPConnectionFactory soapFactory;
        
        @Autowired
        public MyService(MyFormatter formatter, SOAPConnectionFactory soapFactory){
          this.formatter = formatter;
          this.soapConnectionFactory = soapConnectionFactory;
        }

        public MyResponse createSomething(MyRequest request){
          MyResponse response;
          try{
               SOAPConnection connection = soapConnectionFactory.createConnection();
               SOAPMessage soapResponse = connection.call(formatter.formatRequest(request), backsideUrl); // formatRequest(MyRequest request) returns object of SOAPMessage
               response = formatter.formatResponse(soapResponse); // formatResponse(SOAPMessage soapMsg) returns object of MyResponse
               connection.close();
             }
             catch(SOAPException ex){
               logger.error("SOAP Connection Error:{}", ex.toString());
               throw MyCustomException("MyErrorMsg", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
             }
             catch(Exception ex){
               logger.error("Unknown Error:{}", ex.toString());
               throw MyCustomException("UnknownErrorMsg", HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR);
             }
           return response;
        }
    }
```

**MyConfiguration.java**

```java
    @Configuration
    public class MyConfiguration{
      @Value("${ssl.store}")
      private String keyPath;

      @Value("${ssl.token}")
      private String keyPassword;

      @Bean
      public SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory() throws SOAPException{
        return SOAPConnectionFactory.newInstance();
      }

      @Bean
      public void addSSLCertificate() throws KeyStoreException, IOException, CertificateException, NoSuchAlgorithException, UnrecoverableKeyException, KeyManagementException{
        // lines of code which uses @Value annotated keyPath and keyPassword fields
      }
    }
```

**MyServiceTest.java**

```java
    @ExtendWith(SpringExtension.class)
    public class MyServiceTest{
      @Mock
      private SOAPConnectionFactory soapConnectionFactory;

      @Mock
      private SOAPConnection soapConnection;

      @Mock
      private MyFormatter formatter;

      @InjectMocks
      private MyService service;

      private MyRequest request;
      private MyResponse expectedResponse;
      private SOAPMessage soapRequest;
      private SOAPMessage soapResponse;
      
      @BeforeEach
      void initializeObjects() throws SOAPException{
         
         // Lines of code creating an object of MyRequest and setting its field values : request
         // Lines of code creating an object of MyResponse and setting its field values : expectedResponse

         // Lines of code creating an object of SOAPMessage: soapRequest
         // Lines of code creating an object of SOAPMessage: soapResponse         
      }

      @Test
      public void myTestCase(){
        Mockito.when(soapConnectionFactory.createConnection()).thenReturn(soapConnection);
        Mockito.when(formatter.formatRequest(any(MyRequest.class))).thenReturn(soapRequest);
        Mockito.when(soapConnection.call(any(SOAPMessage.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(soapResponse);
        Mockito.when(formatter.formatResponse(any(SOAPMessage.class))).thenReturn(expectedResponse);
        
        MyResponse actualResponse = service.createSomething(request);
        
        Assertions.assertEquals(expectedResponse.toString(), actualResponse.toString()); // overridden toString() method exists in the definition of MyResponse class
      }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

Since the value of String object i.e. backsideUrl is not mocked and hence it will not get assigned, then at the time of `connection.call(formatter.formatRequest(request), backsideUrl)` method execution, the value of backsideUrl will be `null`. So the mock is not going to working properly because we are using `any(String.class)`.

**Instead of this:**

```java
    Mockito.when(soapConnection.call(any(SOAPMessage.class), any(String.class))).thenReturn(soapResponse);
```

**Use this:**

```java
    Mockito.when(soapConnection.call(any(SOAPMessage.class), any())).thenReturn(soapResponse);
```